# How many skill points will I have at max level?

Tags: mass-effect-3

What is the maximum level in Mass Effect 3?

How many skill points will Shepard have at max level?

If NPC companions earn a different number of skill points than Shepard, what's the number they'll have at max level?

Comment: I know [Do I earn enough skill points to unlock everything?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54662/do-i-earn-enough-skill-points-to-unlock-everything) is newer, but it has a more complete answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum character level is 60.

Character level is imported directly from Mass Effect 2, and continues to climb.

Shepard receive 2 skill points at every level, and start with 1 point in their class abilities, giving a maximum point level of 61 for the first 30 levels.

After this, Shepard begins receiving 4 points per level.

Squad mates are simpler - they get exactly half of what Shepard gets, giving them 1 squad point per level, so 30 points at level 30, and 2 onwards from there.

This gives Shepard a total of 181 skill points (enough to fully max out 8 skills) and his squad mates an even 90.

Answer (score 8):

Since this question seems to have been deemed the Canonical by mods:

**The maximum character level is 60. At this level, Shepard will have earned a total of 181 Skill Points.**

Maxing a single skill requires 21 points.

There are enough points in the game to max out a total of 8 skills, with a few left over.

Shepard, conveniently enough, has 8 skills, plus one slot for a Bonus Power.

So, you can come very close to maxing out all skills, but you can't quite make it to maxing out all 9. You can max out 8 of them, and have 13 points remaining for the 9th, which lets you get to rank 4. You'll have 2 points left over. Alternately, you could max out 7 skills, get two to rank 5, and have 3 points left over.