# Do I earn enough skill points to unlock everything?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many skill points will I have at max level?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53536/how-many-skill-points-will-i-have-at-max-level)

I'd like to know if I should expect enough skill points to unlock most of the skills, or if I;m only going to get enough to specialise to the end of a few skill paths.

So, how many skill points are available in total at max level?
And, how many would I need to unlock everything available to Commander Shepard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Johnjon notes, there are 181 skillpoints in the game.

Maxing a single skill requires 21 points.

There are enough points in the game to max out a total of 8 skills, with a few left over.

Shepard, conveniently enough, has 8 skills, plus one slot for a Bonus Power.

So, you can come very close, but you can't quite make it to maxing out all 9. You can max out 8 of them, and have 13 points remaining for the 9th, which lets you get to rank 4. You'll have 2 points left over. Alternately, you could max out 7 skills, get two to rank 5, and have 3 points left over.

Answer (score 2):

To quote [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53536/how-many-skill-points-will-i-have-at-max-level) question:

> The maximum character level is 60.
>
> Character level is imported directly from Mass Effect 2, and continues to climb.
>
> Shepard receives 2 squad points at every level, and start with 1 point in their class abilities, giving a maximum point level of 61 for the first 30 levels.
>
> After this, Shepard begins receiving 4 points per level.

Using math, that adds up to 181 max skill points.

Comment: I'll happily upvote you if you'll answer the second part of OPs question, namely: what do you GET out of this many point?

Comment: Nah, that was my bad. LessPop's got a better full answer. Team effort!

Comment: Upvotes all around, then. <3